# Is it possible to redirect all HTTP pages of website to https except 1 page? -Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, http-redirect

I have a website over HTTPS and all my HTTP pages redirect to HTTPS. I would like to load just 1 special page load on HTTP (book).

My mean is when user enter `http://example.com/book` in address bar load this page on HTTP.

My Nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html/example.com;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Most browsers will not allow you to have mixed content, especially if you use [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). Your config does not allow any page to be served by over HTTP - it always redirects to HTTPS. You will have to add `location` blocks for the pages that you need on HTTP-only.

Comment: @IVOGELOV How can I  add location blocks for the pages?

Comment: I assume you meant to ask `where` because `how` is the same as your other `location` blocks. So for `where` - you need to add them in the first `server` block.